# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character ASP.NET identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net identity for login and authentication.
I am getting error for password field when login with following method

model= is user entity

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    bool isPersistent = false;
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
```

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters

Comment: I am also receiving this problem.  I don't suppose you're using MySQL?  Did you manage to get to the bottom of this problem?

Comment: I am also having this issue, Im using EF. however I did override the Pk from a string to an Int

Comment: You will get the same error if you put invalid hash in Password_Hash

Comment: I agree with user960567.  You can use Postman or write a unit test to create a user with an appropriate password.  Depending on type of encryption, the password will look something like this: BBT+nIr3Mk5nmZNBL8b2vrWFvarWIJxNqefxHWHJ6ykeNGj+DTxt2k5P2eYolnDBOw==

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EF? If so, you shouldnt add AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins and AspNetUserRoles on your edmx.

In addition, I always use "Login" method like below. If I need to keep some info (like userRole, userName etc), I use Session like below.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
        //var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        if (user != null)
        {
            string userRole = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            Session["userRole"] = userRole;
            Session["userName"] = model.Email;
            await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password"); 
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Hence can you try

```
await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
```

or

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync
```